# Secure Login and Registration functionality

Tags: php, security

I want to implement  Secure Login and Registration functionality for my website can any one please guide me on that.

Comment: Please be more specified so that people can tell you what to do.

Answer (score 4):

The answers to all your questions (and many you didn't even knew existed):

[**Stackoverflow.com: The Definitive Guide To Website Authentication (beta)**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/549/the-definitive-guide-to-website-authentication-beta)

Expect it to be quite a learning curve :)